# How to retrieve form data ( key-value pair) in PDF using python and amazon-textract?

Tags: python-3.x, forms, amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I have tried using Analyze Document to retrieve data but this function allowed only image file. So how can I get form data (key-value pair) in PDF file?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to me. But I want through Amazon - Textract only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_document_analysis() , which is an asynchronous call for analyze documents.
Asynchronous calls support PDF.

you can refer this https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/textract.html#Textract.Client.get_document_analysis .